# Only return fields which appear a certain number of times using MySQL DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I am using the below query to return the names of artists which appear in a table multiple times AND the first character is starting with A

```
SELECT DISTINCT artist FROM releases WHERE artist LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY artist
```

I now want to take this a bit further and want to only return artists which appear more than 10 times

How would I do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use a `GROUP BY` to get the counts of the times the artists appear, then using `HAVING` to indicate they need to appear at least a certain number of times.

I believe this query will give you what you want:

```
SELECT artist, count(*) 
FROM releases 
WHERE artist LIKE 'a%'
GROUP BY artist 
ORDER BY artist
HAVING count(*) > 10
```

Comment: Great thanks, just had to tweak your answer slightly - SELECT DISTINCT artist, COUNT( artist ) AS num
         FROM charts_extended
         WHERE artist LIKE 'a%'
         GROUP BY artist
         HAVING num >10
         ORDER BY artist

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT artist, count(*)  FROM releases 
WHERE artist LIKE 'a%' GROUP BY artist
ORDER BY artist
HAVING count(*) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The selection of your query has just the artist name :

```
select artist from releases
where artist like 'a%' group by artist 
having count(distinct(artist))>10;
```

Comment: This would work on postgres - I  haven't used mysql in a while!

Comment: how `(distinct(artist)) > 10 ` it work ? here `distinct` return single artist then how it will be `>10`

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul : You are right,I shouldnt be using distinct inside count.  Thanks for pointing out the same.